# Using flask, how can I return a row of data as a list

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get my route to return a row in a list format but it appears to be returning a concatenation of the row items. How can I return the row of data in list format? Or how can I get a specific row object from the table shown on the page in a general sense to provide that data to a microservice?

Here is what I want it to return:
['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5']

What it appears to return is:
['field1' 'field2' 'field3' 'field4' 'field5']

Here is my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, redirect, request
import pandas as pd 
 
# Flask constructor
app = Flask(__name__)
 
# Data setup
table = pd.read_csv("table.csv")
table.fillna('', inplace=True)
headings = list(table.columns)
print(headings)
data = list(table.values)
print(data)

# Homepage URL call
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", headings=headings, data=data)

@app.route('/GetInfo/<row>')
def GetInfo(row):
    return row

# Listener
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=2509, debug=True)
```

Here is my home.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        {% for header in headings %}
        <th class="cell">{{header}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        <th>Info</th>
      </tr>
      {% for row in data %}
      <tr class="row">
        {% for cell in row %}
        <td>{{cell}}</td>
        {% endfor %}  
        <td><a href="GetInfo/{{row}}">Info</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to send your data as a dictionary. It could be in `render_template()` but instead of sending data as a list, you use data as a dictionary with the key row. Or you could try with Flask'`jsonify()`

Comment: Could you specify why is this behavior a problem ? how are you trying to use the returned data ?

Comment: It's a problem because I need to pass the fields in a row as a list to be used by a microservice which will use the first two or three fields. If there is a way to convert the output I get to a list that would potentially work too.

Comment: You want to navigate to a URL `/GetPlayerInfo/['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5']`? That is a very strange way to pass data to a microservice. Usually you POST JSON or encode query parameters in a GET. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: maybe you need what will be in 2.2.0, judging by [this PR](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4672)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a request with the whole row is unnecessary and requires extra bookkeeping. Instead, use a unique id (preferably) or an index. This identifier gives the server everything it needs to find the resource the client wants to take an action on.

The index is less ideal because if other clients are able to add or remove rows from the dataset after another client has loaded it, things will break. But it looks like your data is static (for now), so an index appears safe.

#### app.py:

```py
@app.route('/info/<int:row_id>')
def info(row_id):
    row = data[row_id]
    response = microservice_get(row) # pretend microservice call
    microservice_payload = json.loads(response.text)
    render_template("info.html", data=microservice_payload) # or whatever
```

#### home.html:

```html
{% for row in data %}
<tr class="row">
  {% for cell in row %}
  <td>{{cell}}</td>
  {% endfor %}  
  <td>
    <a href="{{url_for('info', row_id=loop.index)}}">Info</a>
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is a bit simplified: I've not done error checking and I don't know what the microservice call will look like, so I assume you'll handle that next.

For this example, the handler blocks until the microservice's response arrives. If the request is long-running, you might want to push it onto a work queue and inform the client of the status later on using a server-sent event or similar. But all that is a bit speculative here.

I've taken the liberty to rename the route to `info` which is more in line with typical URLs.